# Creating Custom Function in Excel for Office Add-in

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, yeoman-generator, excel-web-addins

Currently I have an World Add-in which can be used on Excel too by adding Excel as a Host but I just want to know if the same add-in supporting Word and Excel as hosts can be used to create excel functions too.

I've tried to make changes to manifest and webpack.config.js but they don't seem to work.
Is it possible to have a single office add-in supporting Word and Excel with some common features and Custom Excel Functions

Comment: I think that should work. But please provide more details beyond saying "don't seem to work". What do you expect to see and what do you actually see?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have a single office add-in supporting Word and Excel with some common features and Custom Excel Functions

Yes, it is possible to support multiple host applications by a single Office web add-in. You just need to make the required adjustments in the manifest file. But please remember that host-specific features make sense only if the add-in is being run in the host that provides such features (like Excel with custom functions).

By default, an add-in is installable in all Office applications supported by the specified add-in type (that is, Mail, Task pane, or Content). For example, a task pane add-in is installable by default on Access, Excel, OneNote, PowerPoint, Project, and Word.

To ensure that your add-in is installable in a subset of Office applications, use the `Hosts` and `Host` elements in the manifest.

It isn't possible for an add-in manifest to apply to more than one type: `Mail`, `Task pane`, or `Content`. This means that if you want your add-in to be installable on Outlook and on one of the other Office applications, you must create two add-ins, one with a `Mail` type manifest and the other with a `Task pane` or `Content` type manifest.

Read more about that in the [Specify Office applications and API requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements) article.